# entity framework model to database with indexed properties

Tags: c#, indexing, entity-framework-5, edmx

I'm using EF 5.0 and diagram modeler (*.edmx) to create schema and generating database from model, and I was wondering if there is any way to create index on some property (only) via this modeler.

Many thanks for answer or advice.

//edit

I'm working on it, if I success, I'll share a little "how to".

Comment: no worries, but it's not working for me. Seems like in EF 5.0 they have changed something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about [Model-First in the Entity Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362.aspx)

Read the sections about **Generating the DDL** and **Influencing the DDL Generation**

*Update*

Take a look at this example too: [Entity Framework Part 5 Model First : Create a database with the Complex Types.](http://www.thebuttonfactory.nl/?p=756)

Comment: do you think that creating new entity with relationship (1 to 1) with main entity (and cascade on delete) will replace indexed property?

Comment: @eCorke - I cannot understand you comment )

Comment: :-) ... I thought if creating new entity (with only one property, which is also key), using it as foreign key for the first, would behave like indexed. But it's quite stupid.

About another article, the Complex property, isn't it some kind of "enum"? I didn't really get point of that example. :(